# Hibernate Key-Generation

Tags: java, hibernate

I defined the primary-key of my entity Attribute like this:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

My option values are mapped in the entity Attribute:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "attribute")
    public Set<AttributeOptions> getAttributeOptionses() {
```

The primary keys of AttributesOptions are the attributeId and a optionId.
The problem: Primary key of the AttributeOptions is not generated, if I persist/create the Attribut-Entity with new AttributeOptions. How can I fix that?

Thx, Simone

Comment: Don't do that, really. Use a single-column, autogenerated ID for all your entities, for your own good. There is 0 reson to include the attribute ID in the primary key of the option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two Integer (or int) attributes in AttributeOption's primary key? Post the code. The two attributes of primary key will be generating if you use `@GeneratedValue`, but it will happens if the attributes are Integer.